# Some confusions while applying Cauchy's Theorem (Local Form)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a couple of confusions surrounding the correct use of Cauchy's Theorem to compute integrals using techniques in complex analysis. I'm using the following local version of the following theorem:

\begin{align}
\textbf{} \text{Suppose that} \; \Delta \; \text{is  an open disk in the complex plane and that} \; f \; \text{is a function which is analytic 
in $\Delta$ (or, more generally, is continuous in} \; \Delta \; \text{and analytic in} \; \Delta \setminus\{z_0\}. \text{Then,} \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 0 \; \text{for every closed, piecewise smooth 
path } \; \gamma \; \text{in} \; \Delta
\end{align}

I have the following confusions:

1. On the contour $\gamma(t) =  2 \cos t + i \sin t, \; t \in [0, 2\pi]$, I'm trying to evaluate the integral,

\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z}
\end{align}

Since the contour encloses a pole of this function, I expect the integral to be non-zero. But a direct computation using the given contour shows that the integral is zero! Here's a sketch of the computation:

Noting that $\dot{\gamma}(t) = -2 \sin t + i \cos t$, the integral is:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} dt \; \frac{-2 \sin t + i \cos t}{2 \cos t + i \sin t}.
\end{align}

Letting $a = 2 \cos t + i \sin t$, a change of variable shows that the new limits under the change of variable are $2$ and $2$!

For a circle of radius 1, a direct computation yields a non-zero answer. What's going on? I can compute the answer by considering a closed path formed by paths for the ellipse and the circle, where one closed path lies in the right-half plane, and the other lies in the left half-plane. Using the analyticity of the function in these domains, the answer, $2 \pi i$, is readily computed. What goes wrong with a direction computation though?

2. For $b > 0$, I wish to show that,

\begin{align}
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \cos(2 b \pi t) = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-b^2 \pi^2}  
\end{align}

The textbook recommends using the function $e^{-z^2}$ over the a rectangular contour defined by vertices $-c, c, c + i b \pi, -c + i b \pi$.

I understand the motivation of choosing this contour from previous exercises, but I am not sure why is the function $e^{- z^2}$ chosen? Since the integral with the $\sin(2b\pi t)$ replaced with $\cos(2 b \pi t)$ is clearly zero, shouldn't we consider the function $e^{- z^2 + iz}$?

Comment: Plus, no residue theorem for point number 1. I haven't covered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You must have made a mistake in your direct computation.  The contour you mentioned is a simple Jordan curve containing the origin in its interior so the line integral should be the residue of the function at the point (namely, $1$) times $2\pi$.

Your change of variable is not legitimate because it does not enable you to replace all occurrences of $t$ by $a$, so it does not  help you to compute the integral.

Comment: That was a typo. I have edited the computation sketched above.